# Having trouble getting a command that sends based on the amount entered to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command that repeats a message based on the number that you input. For example, if I did -ping 4 it would say pong back 4 times. My code for the functionality of the command at the moment (separate from the main file) is:

```js
async execute(message, args) {
    if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send("`Command Usage:\n-rqplay (amount)`");
    if(isNaN(args[1])) return message.channel.send("Please enter an actual number idiot :rolling_eyes:");
    
    if(args[1] > 15) return message.channel.send("I don't want to send that many messages :nauseated_face:");
    if(args[1] < 1) return message.reply("Bro come on, are this stupid?");
    
    await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[1]}).then(_messages =>{
        message.channel.send('@everyone play');
    });
}
```

However the bot only returns with one command. Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

I'm using the latest Discord.js, VSCode, and node.js.

Comment: I am still new to some parts of js and discord.js

Answer (score 0):

With `await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[1]})` you are fetching the channel's messages with a limit of whatever number they provided.

If you would like to send a message to the channel however many times they provided, you could use this:

```js
async execute(message, args) {
        if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send("`Command Usage:\n-rqplay (amount)`");
        if(isNaN(args[1])) return message.channel.send("Please enter an actual number idiot :rolling_eyes:");

        if(args[1] > 15) return message.channel.send("I don't want to send that many messages :nauseated_face:");
        if(args[1] < 1) return message.reply("Bro come on, are this stupid?");

        for (let i = 0; i < args[1]; i++) {
           message.channel.send('@everyone play');
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) at the bottom used to send the messages.

Comment: I forgot the for loop and added yours, the code looks right with the docs but now the bot just responds to anything, doesn't do any of the arguments and only sends 1 message